# How can I import a list of words and shortcuts into my Android Personal Dictionary?

Tags: 9.0-pie, gboard, dictionary

jc able

ab about

bv above

ac account

This is a sample of the words and shortcuts that I'm trying to add into my Personal Dictionary. I've tried exporting my current dictionary with shortcuts and the text file inside of the zip contains this:

# Gboard Dictionary version:1

q   ing

# From OS

jc  able
t   the

I'm able to import the above file, but as soon as I copy and paste my words into it I'm hit with an "Import failed" toast.

[Here"s](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18-UAXzfM7mO6LR79HTQr0s4b7AWC0z0W/view?usp=drivesdk) the full wordlist that I'm trying to copy and paste into the other file.

I've also tried the User Dictionary Manager app with no success as it doesn't seem to support shortcuts for words. It just assumes that the shortcut is part of the word.

Why isn't this working? What do I have to do too make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at your file and couldn't import the words to Gboard either. There are 3 errors that make Gboard ignore your words and shortcuts: space between words & shortcuts and no language for the words.

### Error 1:  Space between words & shortcuts

Your words and shortcuts are separated by spaces. That's not correct. They must be separated by <kbd>Tab</kbd>. I didn't know that either. I created some words and shortcuts, then exported them. When I opened the exported file in a code editor, only then could I see that the separator was not a space but a tab character.

### Error 2:  No language for the words

This error is minor. Your words didn't belong to any dictionary language. It seems when you don't add the language, the words & shortcuts are not imported or GBoard just decides to ignore and select a language for you (I have not checked why). So, you must add a language at the end of each words separated of course by Tab characters.

### Error 3:  No dictionary version

Add the dictionary version at start of the file. GBoard ignores the language (see Error 2) which is bad if like me you have many languages enabled.

I have not found yet how to add words to the "All languages" dictionary (although you didn't ask).

Comment: I imported to "all languages" successfully, i had a line at the top of the file like this "# Gboard Dictionary version: 1"